# If someone has a certain permission/role make them exempt from a profanity filter discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

So I have made a profanity filter for my discord bot and it works perfectly. I would like it to not affect people with a certain role or permission. I know how to use the decorator @commands.has_role("name") and @commands.has_permissions([ban_members=True, kick_members=True])  but I don't know how to implement this into my bot. Here is the code

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_message(self, message):
    if not message.author.bot:
      if profanity.contains_profanity(message.content):
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send("You can't say that here")
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can check is your role in message author's roles if message has attribute guild like:

```
if not message.author.bot:
  if message.guild:
    if your_role in message.author.roles:
      return
```